# Bound sensitivity of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, roots

Given a polynomial $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n$, let the sensitivity be the largest number $\epsilon$ such that for all $-\epsilon < c < \epsilon$,  we have that $P(x) + c$ has the same number of real roots as $P(x)$.

Can we give an upper bound of $\epsilon$ in terms of the coefficients?

I think the bounds of $\epsilon$ occur when $P(x) \pm \epsilon$ has a double root. So, I need a way to bound what values of $\epsilon$ create a double root.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe there exists a closed-form expression giving an upper bound (I assume you want a fairly tight upper bound) of $\epsilon$ in terms of the polynomial coefficients?

Comment: I think there might be something that somehow makes use of the discriminant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It makes sense the discriminant could be a factor in your answer. The [Real Roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Real_roots) section of Wikipedia's "Discriminant" article says, for a positive discriminant, the # of non-real roots is a multiple of $4$, while for a negative discriminant, the # of non-real roots *not* a multiple of $4$. Thus, the discriminant switching between positive & negative is one "trigger" point for changing the # of real roots.

Comment: I don't think that such an expression exists in general case. $\epsilon = \min(f(x_i))$ where $\{x_i\}$ is the set of local extremums of our polynomial. So to get our value we will need to now at least one of the solution of the equation of degree $n-1$